# Flutter Webview onStateChanged is not getting triggered

Tags: flutter, webview, stream

I have a stless widget where i open a webview to perform oAuth. I want to be able to track when the user gets to a certain page and close the webview.

Currently even the print statement is not getting executed! Moreover i am noticing that in the StreamSubsctiption portion it says "The value of the field '_onWebviewStateChange' isn't used."

What am i doing wrong?

My Code:

```
class RedditAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'redditAuth';

  @override
  _RedditAuthState createState() => _RedditAuthState();
}

class _RedditAuthState extends State<RedditAuth> {
  // Initialise the RedditAuthClass and the FlutterWebviewPlugin
  RedditAuthClass authorizeReddit = RedditAuthClass();
  FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  // Subscribe to the WebViewStateChanged
  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onWebviewStateChange;
  //
  @override
  void intiState() {
    super.initState();
    _onWebviewStateChange = flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen(
      (WebViewStateChanged state) {
        print('State has changed: ${state.url}');
        if (state.url == 'https://www.google.com') {
          flutterWebviewPlugin.hide();
        }
      },
    );
  }

//  @override
  //Dispose any stream subs

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('data'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebviewScaffold(
          url: authorizeReddit.auth(),
          hidden: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i changed this part of the code it started working. Now i need to figure out why:

final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();